# ¿Cómo hacer que no aparezca el menú en dispositivos móvil?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Al ver la página en un navegador tengo el menú de navegación, ¿cómo hago para que cuando se vea la web en un dispositivo móvil, desaparezca el menú?

Comment: Deberas utilizar una media query para que cuando la anchura de la pantalla sea pequeña, aplicar un hidden al menú.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar los media query y decirle que sea `display: none;` cuando tenga ese tamaño.

De esta forma cuando tengas un ancho mínimo 414px el header sera ocultado con display: none;

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 414px){
    header {
         display: none; 
    }
}
```